# Use curl to download from a Url

Tags: curl, download, openssl, ssl, url

I am trying to download a file from a url using `curl`:

```
$ curl -3 -v "https://atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?location=XXXXXXXXXXX_14zbwk&rid=027"
```

Where the X is a digit in the phone number of the device I am testing on.

but I am running into an error:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x2140cd0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x2140cd0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 66.94.0.188...
* Connected to atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com (66.94.0.188) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Bothell; O=T-Mobile USA, Inc.; CN=apgw.sipgeo.t-mobile.com
*    start date: 2013-05-21 21:02:44 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-05-22 08:35:43 GMT
*    subjectAltName: atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference; OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /mms/wapenc?location=18188257544_14zbwk&rid=027 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
< Server: BigIP
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com left intact`
```

What does the `501 not implemented` error mean?  How can I get around this?

Comment: My bet would be that it blocks based on the User-Agent, try passing a MSIE/Mozilla-like user agent with the `-A` option.

Comment: Hey @StephaneChazelas, i get the same response when i run `curl -3 -v -A Mozilla/5.001 "https://atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?location=18188257544_14zbwk&rid=027"
`

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the -3 from the command line?

Comment: Yes @YoMismo, I just tried that and got this error `* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to atl1mmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com:443 `

Comment: Ok I tried your url on my browser and I get the exact same error. It is not a curl problem.... Do you get to that url from a previous page where you introduce some credentials? It could be a cookie problem

Comment: Ok so it may not be an issue with curl or any other unix utility.  But then how can I access that url?

Comment: IIRC you needed to login to your t-mobile service account before you can access mms messages. But that was t-mobile.de and several years ago. Have you tried that?

Comment: I just tried logged in to my t-mobile account on a desktop.  Then I tried running accessing that url in a browser but it still does not display anything or attempt to download anything

Answer (score 1):

The error code is provided by the server side, not by curl. It is an HTTP error code and the description for that can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

```
501 Not Implemented
The server either does not recognize the request method, or it lacks the 
ability to fulfill the request. Usually this implies future availability 
(e.g., a new feature of a web-service API).
```

You should try to get access to the functionality with a real browser, to make sure this works (the url you provided doesn't work in my browser). Once that works you can try deleting any cookies to see if accessing the page depends on any of that. You might have to go for something like using selenium if you want to automate accessing that page.

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable.  The problem is I have an mms message on Android and the "content-location" is this url.  That is why I am trying to fetch the url to download the content of the MMS.  So what are my alternatives?

Comment: I am not able to access this url in a browser so that is why I am looking to a unix utility to download the file.

Comment: However as you indicate this is for downloading an MMS you might not be able to do this unless you can be identified as the owner of the phone where the MMS was sent to. Is the 18188257544 part of your phone number? Have you ever tried to do this via a normal browser, it might ask you to identify, or identify you use this from a t-online connection (DSL)

Comment: yes that number is from the device that I am testing on.  Have I tried to do what via a normal browser?

Comment: I am not sure, somehow t-online should check the validity of you accessing that data. The `14zbwk` seems a bit minimal for that. Are you using a t-online provided internet access for this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by using a t-online provided internet access.

Comment: Hmmm so you can get to that page from your phone but not from a PC browser? In that case @Stephane Chazelas might be right, try with this user agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3; en-us) AppleWebKit/999+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/999.9

Comment: @toobsco42 Who is providing your access to the internet? And think about how t-online.com knows you are the person allowed to access that message and not someone else.

Comment: @YoMismo, I cannot access that url from a mobile browser or from a desktop browser.

Comment: @Anthon, The phone bill is under contract with T-Mobile.

Comment: @toobsco42 Yeah, but you are not using that phone to do curl access do you? I think you better call customer support for your phone to get this resolved.

Comment: I am running curl from my desktop.

Comment: @toobsco42, then I don't understand. From where are you accessing that URL with success? If it is a specific application, then you might need to sniff packets to see what exactly is being sent from that application so that you can reproduce that information exchange from curl.

Comment: I am not able to successfully access this URL anywhere.  This url is part of the body of a WAP_PUSH_MESSAGE on Android.  Thats where I got the URL from.

Comment: I don't know about WAP_PUSH_MESSAGE, could you check if information is being POSTed in that body?, some information might be send with POST and you need to feed that same info in your curl command.